# How to add style to the MVC3 application and use it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Just starting programming, so don`t kick too hard, question is pretty self explanatory, but I can not find detailed guides in internet, so I would like to know the **whole** process of adding style to an a MVC3 application (Razor engine)

Well I ment CSS of course, but I`ve literally began working with VS10 (and VS at all not so long ago (not even for a week))

Comment: Learn about Cascading Style Sheets (CSS).

Comment: Hello CSS!, http://dosdd.com/css-hello-world/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Razor is really good giving you nice and clean HTML code, that's its objective, so you shouldn't have any problem styling it with css, styling an ASP.NET MVC app it's not any different than styling a plain HTML page, or php app, ruby app, etc.
If you create a new css file you should put it in the "Content" folder and then call it from your view like this:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/YourCssFile.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

If you are new with css I recommend you to watch this [tutorials from google](http://code.google.com/intl/es/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/#css).

Answer (score 0):

Open the Content folder in the Solution Explorer.  There's a file called `Site.css`.  That's where your CSS goes.

Comment: Thanks! I would Click Answer is useful, but do not have 15 rep, but however as I said: I would like to know the whole process of adding style to an a MVC3 application (Razor engine)

Comment: Make sure that you have `<link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/Site.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />` in your view and you're good to go.  If you want to learn CSS and how it works, that's whole different thing...